# Compiler warnings conversion

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-warnings, integer-promotion

We are compiling using gcc with `-Wconversion` enabled. I get following warnings when I left shift result returned by `isBitSet` function below.

> warning: conversion to 'u_int16_t {aka short unsigned int}' from 'int'
>   may alter its value [-Wconversion]

```
#include <stdint.h>

using namespace std;

void convertToPos(uint16 in) {

    auto isBitSet = [&in](uint8_t position) -> bool{
        return (in & (1 << position));
    };

    uint16_t signal = 0;
    signal |= isBitSet(1) << 9;  // Calibrated
    signal |= isBitSet(2) << 10; // Corresponds to digital map
    signal |= isBitSet(5) << 13; // DR
    signal |= isBitSet(8) << 15; // 3D Fix

}

int main(int argc)
{
    convertToPos(4);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried changing lambda to below, but still I get the same error. How can I fix it?

```
auto isBitSet = [&in](uint8_t position) -> uint16_t {
    return (in & (1 << position)) ? 1u:0u;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid the warning, you may do:

```
signal = uint16_t(signal | isBitSet(1u) << 9);
```

as `operator |` promotes operator `uint16_t` to `int`.

Comment: Better, IMO, would be `signal |= uint16_t(isBitSet(1) << 9);`. (Here too, the promotion still happens, and technically, you do implicitly convert an `int` to `uint16_t`, but GCC is supposed to realise that the result of `uint16_t | uint16_t` can always be safely assigned to another `uint16_t`.)

Comment: @hvd: I still have warning with `signal |= uint16_t(isBitSet(1) << 9);` :-( (gcc 4.8.1).

Comment: Huh. Testing shows you're right. `signal |= uint16_t(...)` gives a warning, `signal = signal | uint16_t(...)` doesn't give a warning. What made `signal |= uint16_t(...)` better (again, IMO) was avoiding having to repeat `signal`, but it appears to be unavoidable.

Answer (score 2):

In this case both *shift operators* and *bitwise inclusive or operator* apply the [integer promotions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast#Integral_promotion) to their operands and since `uint16_t` can be represented by *int* the operands are promoted to *int* and therefore `gcc` is warning you that the conversion from a larger type *int* to *uint16_t* may result in loss.

The C++ way to deal with this is to use [static_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast), it looks like the following works:

```
signal = signal | static_cast<uint16_t>(isBitSet(1) << 9);
```

it looks like it is not neccessary to cast the result of `|`, although strictly it should be no different than `<<` but I guess `gcc` is able to deduce that it is okay in this case. Technically this is better:

```
signal = static_cast<uint16_t>( signal | isBitSet(1) << 9);
```

For reference the draft C++ standard in `5.8` *Shift operators* says:

> The operands shall be of integral or unscoped enumeration type and
>   integral promotions are performed.[...]

and section `5.13` *Bitwise inclusive OR operator* says:

> The usual arithmetic conversions are performed;[...]

the *usual arithmetic conversions* in this case ends up applying the *integer promotions*.

Answer (score -1):

It's not an error. What it's saying is that by converting from an integer to an unsigned integer, the value will change if the integer is negative. There's really no "fix" for this; you just need to be careful what values the unsigned is taking from the signed. I'm guessing you're using unsigned because it needs to be 0 and above, so if anything, this will fix any accidentally-entered negative values.